# install windows after installing ubuntu and kali?

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

Hello  have dual boot my laptop Running Kali linux 1.0.7 and Ubuntu 14.04. For some Application i need windows,As wine does not support that apps and not have sufficient RAM to run windows in virtual machine,
**my Question**: i have ubuntu's grub loaded in my laptop, so when i delete kali linux partition and made un-allocated space , can i install windows 7 in that un-allocated space? if yes after installing windows 7 should i need to re-install grub (i don't think so because i have ubuntu's boot loader) and install kali after installing windows 7

Comment: But Do i have need to reinstall grub ?

Comment: See the last five steps in Peachy's answer; that's the easiest way to repair your Grub bootloader after installing Windows. After you have finished installing Windows, install and run the boot-repair application when running an Ubuntu live DVD/USB, and then repair the Grub bootloader using boot-repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can install windows 7 on the unallocated space. Once you do that the Windows bootloader MIGHT recognize Ubuntu and add it as an option. Otherwise you can reinstall GRUB to the MBR by booting using the live cd and running  sudo grub-install /dev/sda